# Can I run Java code stored as a string in a Json Object?

Tags: java, json, compilation, conditional-statements

I have a program which takes collections of records and a series of JSON objects which represent actions or "steps" to carry out in sequence on this data in Java. I would like to add a "condition" field to the steps, which the backend can use to skip over a step if said condition is met.

Here is an example of one of the json steps:

```
//previous steps...
,{
      "closureType": "FILTER",
      "configParams": {
        "usingDataset": "DATASET1",
        "condition": {
          "operation": "OR",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "field": "eve",
              "value": 0,
              "operation": "EQ"
            },
            {
              "field": "eve",
              "value": 0,
              "operation": "LT"
            }
          ]
        },
        "resultingDataset": "DATASET2"
      }
    },
//subsequent steps
```

This step tells the backend to remove all records that do not match the filter conditions from DATASET1 and stores whatever is left in DATASET2, where they can then be acted on by subsequent steps.

However I would like to add a condition that should be executed before the rest of the step to determine whether the filter actually occurs.

```
{
      "closureType": "FILTER",
      "condition": "[Java If...Then code]"
      "configParams": {
        "usingDataset": "DATASET1",
        "condition": {
          "operation": "OR",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "field": "eve",
              "value": 0,
              "operation": "EQ"
            },
            {
              "field": "eve",
              "value": 0,
              "operation": "LT"
            }
          ]
        },
        "resultingDataset": "DATASET2"
      }
    },
```

As a more concrete example:

```
{
      "closureType": "FILTER",
      "condition": "if(transformContext.datasets.get(DATASET1).hasField(fieldname)){break;}"
      "configParams": {
        "usingDataset": "DATASET1",
        "condition": {
          "operation": "OR",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "field": "eve",
              "value": 0,
              "operation": "EQ"
            },
            {
              "field": "eve",
              "value": 0,
              "operation": "LT"
            }
          ]
        },
        "resultingDataset": "DATASET2"
      }
    },
```

Which would prevent the step from running if the datarecords in DATASET1 have a field called "fieldname".

However as far as I can tell this is not possible in Java as the code must be compiled before running. I saw some mention of using Groovy but am completely unfamiliar with it so not really sure where to start. Is there any way to do this or any alternative suggestions?

Comment: if you really know what you're doing, and are willing to write the code needed to get this done: yes

Comment: If you are ok with scripting: [The Java Scripting API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html), [Java Scripting Programmer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/)

Comment: Check out Java's `ClassLoader`s and how they work, if you want to run the code in full Java (opposed to scripting). If so, I'd suggest you define an `interface`, create a template class that implements this interface, insert the code you wanna run into that template, load that template via ClassLoader, and the call it. There's lots of other possibilities, too, but I think this is the most stable.

Comment: Thanks @Fildor this looks pretty interesting. Familiar with JS but never tried to use it alongside Java like this.

Comment: You're welcome. May be overkill, though.